# Show that there exists a real function $f$ such that $x\to a, |f(x)|\to |L|$ but the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Show that there exists a real function $f$ such that $x\to a, |f(x)|\to |L|$ but the limit of $f(x)$ does not exist.

Just before this problem I was asked to prove the theorem:

If $L=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists, then $|f(x)|\to|L|$ as $x\to a$.

I was able to prove that just fine which is causing the confusion here. I was under the impression that in order to have
$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L, f(x)$ must approach L whenever $x$ approaches $a$. Based on that, how do we create an example where the limit does not exist?

Comment: You're not supposed to use the first part to prove the second. The second part is meant to show that the converse of the first part is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic Dirchlet Function,

$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x \in \Bbb Q \\ 
 -1& x \notin \Bbb Q
\end{matrix}\right..$$

Notice $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x \to 0} | f(x) | = 1.$

Comment: Or more simply, $x<0$ and $x \geq 0$.

Comment: @user180040, I just *love* to complicate things don't I?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Take $a = 0$ and $L = 1$, for example. Can you find an example where $|f(x)|$ is constant, but $f(x)$ has no limit at $0$?

Comment: Would this work? Let $f(x)=\large\frac{x+1}{x}$ and $L=-1$ and $a=0$ then $-1=\lim_{x\to 0}\large\frac{x+1}{x}$? Because $\large\frac{x+1}{x+1-1}=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$ And the limit does not exist?

Comment: No, the limit of $|(x+1)/x|$ at zero is $+\infty$, but $L$ is supposed to be finite.

Answer (score 2):

The classic Sign Function is also Okay:

$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & x>0 \\ 
 0 & x =0 \\
-1 & x<0
\end{matrix}\right..$$

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ does not exist, but $\lim_{x \to 0} | f(x) | = 1.$